# CSS - layout of the sidebar starting from the left side of the screen (see picture)

Tags: html, css

How i can code layout like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjkeD.png

Here demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ymC82/

current code html:

```
<div class="wrapper">

    <aside>
        Sidebar        
    </aside>

    <article>
          Content 
    </article>

</div>
```

current code css:

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.wrapper{
    max-width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

aside{
    padding: 50px 0;
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #aaa;
}

article{
    padding: 50px 0;
    width: 70%;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #777;
}
```

red line is a container.
please help with this.

Comment: show us what u tried ?

Comment: If you can't show what you've tried this question will likely be taken down due to its broadness. To point you in the right direction look into inline-block, floating, percentage widths and/or flexbox.

Comment: nothing, I think as you do. and looking for a way / idea

I div.sidebar and div.content, both figures float: left,. sidebar {width: 30%;} and. content {width: 70%;}

Comment: I have a percentage, but I do not know how to reduce this content by container

Comment: The stackoverflow community is for answering questions.  If you have code that isn't working and you want help, post away.  But we're not here to do your work for you.  I hope I'm not coming off as rude by saying this.  We want to help you, but by solving your problem, not writing your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using CSS3 property box-sizing, you can achieve easily this kind of layout.

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">

   <aside>
    <p>Content Goes Here</p>    
   </aside>

   <article>
      <p>Content Goes Here</p>
   </article>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
 *{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

.wrapper{
 margin: 0 auto;
}

aside{
padding:50px 0 50px 10%;
width: 30%;
float:left;
background: #aaa;
box-sizing:border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
}

article{
padding:50px 10% 50px 0;
width: 70%;
float:left;
background: #777;
box-sizing:border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

[**Have a Fiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ymC82/19/)

Answer (score 0):

Quick-and-dirty solution: a background div. http://jsfiddle.net/VwWjp/

```
div.halfbg{
    background-color:#aaa;
    min-width:180px;
    width:calc(50% - 120px);
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    z-index:-999;
}
```